# How to associate PFUsers to PFInstallations on the fly to send push notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

Based on the Parse [guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/iOS) to using Advanced Targeting for push notifications, I understand in order to associate `PFInstallations` with the **current** user, one should so in the following manner:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

My question is, how would be able to do this "on the fly" for other users (i.e. not the current user).  For example, I have a `Message` object that I would like to send to users Sally, Alex and Ben: how would be able to get just the PFInstallations of those users based on their user objectIds, and then set their PFInstallation's so that

```
//Sally, Alex and Ben's PFInstallations:
[installation setObject:YES forKey:message.objectId];
```

...so then when I sent out the message, only Sally, Alex and Ben will get the push notification that they received a message from me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here was how I managed to do it. Note that `recipientIDs` are the list of users (user objectIds, to be exact) that I am sending a push notification to.

```
if (recipientIDs.count > 0){

        //Find the users that were just sent the message
        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
        [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:recipientIDs];

        //Find the devices associated with these users
        PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
        [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:userQuery];

        //Send push to these users
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New message from %@", [PFUser currentUser].username], @"alert",
                              @"Increment", @"badge",
                              nil];
        [push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
        [push setData:data];
        [push sendPushInBackground];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can work - the documentation says

> A valid PFInstallation can only be instantiated via [PFInstallation
>   currentInstallation] because the required identifier fields are
>   readonly.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html

Comment: Thanks for answering @rist. I understand that a PFInstallation could only be instantiated from the currentInstallation. My question is, once a user has instantiated, and their user ID is associated with that PFInstallation, could I then query for that installation and then modify the elements based on that query. Since PFInstallation is a subclass of PFObject, I had thought this would be possible.  Thanks.